# Access variable of the returning object in Freemarker

Tags: freemarker

I have an addNewRow() method that returns a object which gets displayed through the Freemarker template. There is a scenario where I need to check if one of the fields of the returning object has the value of -1. I tried the following syntax unsuccessfully.

```
 <#if ${Object.field} ==-1>
 <#if Object.field ==-1>
```

How can I access the object variable in this case?

Comment: The 1st is syntactically wrong (as the error message explains). What happens in the second case? Do you have a public `getField()` method on that object?

Comment: I get an  - Expression Object.field is undefined message, the getField() method is public and the object returned also has a public get method iin the ActionClass

Comment: Then I see two possibilities. Either `getField()` returns `null`, or the class itself that has the `getField()` method isn't public.

Comment: I was able to do a bit more digging into it today - The error only shows up in the cases where field value is !=-1. However the field has a value in these cases as well. Also this object belongs to list object where I am able to display data on the jsp by using name="List[${rowNum}].Object.field", so maybe its not a visibility issue?

Comment: As `Object.field` itself is missing or `null` (according the error message quoted earlier), what do you mean by "where field value is !=-1"?

Comment: Thanks, your comment made me check the returning function and it turns out that there is a scenario where the field value was not set by the method that was called, which was causing the error message.

Comment: BTW, you can handle that like `(Object.field!0) ==-1` or `(Object.field!-1) ==-1`, depending on if a `null` field counts as -1 or not.